# Освободить virtio устройство

Tags: linux

Не люблю измененные дистрибутивы хостинговыми компаниями, пусть даже один motd, поэтому первым делом решил установить  чистый дистрибутив Debian, скачал через debootstrap, поднял в chroot ssh сервер на другом порте, после чего подключился к по ssh в chroot, полностю отвязавшись от основного корня, затер диск с помощу dd и начал размечать с помощу fdisk, но после попытки сохранить все то что я разместил получил сообщение о том что устройство занято.
Я это предвидел и попробовал отключить диск командой `echo 1 > /sys/block/vda/device/delete` но потом понял что это не годится для виртуальных устройств.
Подскажите, как мне освободить диск для последующей разметки без перезагрузки?

Answer (score 0):

На опеннете совсем недавно был [подробно описан метод](http://www.opennet.ru/tips/3007_linux_remote_install_ssh_init_busybox_mount.shtml) подобной переустановки.

Думаю, что вы забыли поубивать все процессы базовой системы и размонтировать диск. И да, chroot для этого необходимо делать за пределы базовой FS, в приведённом методе — в tmpfs.

Comment: 1. Скрипт плохо работает(пути к бинарным фацлам не правильный, в old_root не смонтировал диск) 2. Подкоректировал, всеровно тоже самое, диск занят, там вроде и не идеться о разметке диска, только о замене его содержимого, а мне нужно разметить